# Grouping objects in a map

Tags: java

This may be trivial, but I need to ensure I do it the correct way.

I have a person object which has property `country_id`. I need to group persons based upon `country_id` and then finally pack then into 1 Map object. The Map should have the key as the `country_id` and its value as List of person objects that belong to that `country_id.`

So the flow should be:

- Iterate through person objects
- Find `country_id` and put in a list. e.g `person A(id=10)` in list_A
- Similarly `person B(id-20)` in list_B
- And then put them in HashMap?

My final o/p should be `PersonMap(country_id-<PersonList>,country_id-<PersonList> )`

Is this approach correct or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put people in the `Map` as you loop through them.  Simply look for the list you need in the map and if you don't find it create it and put it in the map.

Assuming `country_id` is an `int` and not using `PersonMap` as I don't know how that works:

```
Map<Integer,List<Person>> map = new HashHap<Integer,List<Person>>();

for (Person person : collectionOfPeople) {
    int cid = person.getCountryId();

    List<People> list = map.get(cid);

    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<People>();
        map.put(cid,list);
    }

    list.add(person);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a nice [index](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) method, that returns a *Multimap* indexed by the expression.

```
ListMultimap<Integer, Person> multimap = Multimaps.index(personList, new Function<Person, Integer>(){
  public Integer apply(Person source){
    return source.getCountryId();
  }
});
```

The Multimap itself can be viewed as a Map, if you need that:

```
Map<Integer, Collection<Person>> map = multimap.asMap();
```

An even nicer, fluent API is available through [LambdaJ's grouping function](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures#Grouping_items):

```
Group<Person> group = group(personList, by(on(Person.class).getCountryId()));
```

However, LambdaJ's Group object does not have any methods that convert it into a map, so you must do this from hand. But maybe you can change the interface so that you can return a Group.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use Google Guava project

**Implementing GroupBy using Google guava Multimap and Function**

This is one way of creating a group by like functionality for collections using google guava Multimap and Function.

Code is straight forward we simply use the  `index` method of the `Multimap` to group our data by, in here we use our 2 column to group it by the department.

## Sample output

```
key = Dev
  1 : Greg
  3 : Roman
key = Support
  2 : Leo
  4 : Jobby
```

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimaps;

public class GroupByMultimap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] o1 = new Object[] { 1, "Greg", "Dev" };
        Object[] o2 = new Object[] { 2, "Leo", "Support" };
        Object[] o3 = new Object[] { 3, "Roman", "Dev" };
        Object[] o4 = new Object[] { 4, "Jobby", "Support" };

        List<Object[]> rows = Lists.newArrayList(o1, o2, o3, o4);
        Multimap<String, Object[]> grouped = Multimaps.index(rows,
                new Function<Object[], String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String apply(Object[] item) {
                        return (String) item[2];
                    }
                });

        Iterator<String> keyIterator = grouped.asMap().keySet().iterator();
        while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = keyIterator.next();
            System.out.println("key = " + key);
            Collection<Object[]> dataRows = grouped.get(key);
            for (Object[] o : dataRows) {
                System.out.println(String.format("  %d : %s", o[0], o[1]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could implement [comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) on person object that uses country id as value to compare, your person objects could then be ordered by country.